# Convergence of the bias potential in well-tempered metadynamics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, molecular-dynamics

I have trouble understanding how the bias potential $V(s,t)$ in well-tempered metadynamics is related to the free-energy $F(s)$ by a simple relation as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Around equation 4 in the [well-tempered metadynamics paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3861) the authors state:

> This implies that $V(s,t\rightarrow \infty) = - \frac{\Delta T}{\Delta T + T}F(s)$, modulo a constant.

How can I justify this result with the information given in the paper?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the approach from [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4300) where (below equation 14) the authors let $\dot{V}(s,t)=C(t)$. That is, they set the rate to a constant with respect to the collective variables $s$.

Plugging this into the rate expression for the large time limit gives

$$ C(t) = \omega \exp\big[-V(s,t)/\Delta T\big] \frac{\exp\big[-\big(F(s)+V(s,t)\big)/T\big]}{\underbrace{\int ds \exp\big[-\big(F(s)+V(s,t)\big)/T\big]}_\text{Q(t)}} .$$

Taking the logarithm on both sides we get

$$ \ln C(t) = \ln \omega -V(s,t)/\Delta T - F(s)/T - V(s,t)/T - \ln Q(t).$$

Grouping the logs of $C(t)$, $\omega$ and $Q(t)$ into a different constant $C'(t)$ and solving for the bias potential gives

$$V(s,t) = -F(s)\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta T + T} + C'(t),$$

which is the desired result.